# Excel is corrupting when populating dropdown using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

 Dim LastRow As Long 
 LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 Dim iRow As Long
 For iRow = 2 To LastRow
    AddListValidation ws.Cells(iRow, "C"), ws.Cells(iRow, "B")
 Next iRow
End Sub


Sub AddListValidation(cellSource As Range, cellTarget As Range)
 cellTarget.Value = "Select your values here"
 With cellTarget.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=cellSource.Value
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
 End With
End Sub
```

First time the dropdown is getting populated. When I do some changes on the sheet and when i reopen the sheet again, its saying that its corrupted and am not getting the dropdown as well.

can anyone help me pls?

The Formula which I used is correct or not?

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=cellSource.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the `cellSource` is empty and thus it gives error at `Formula1`, which is trying to get its value.

Write in your code after the `Sub AddListValidation`  this line:

```
If Len(cellSource) Then Exit Sub
```

Thus, it will exit, if the `cellSource` is empty and will avoid the error.

Comment: cellSource is not empty. It has value at all time.

Comment: @aaroki - what is the value?

Comment: cellSource value is = a,b,c,d. Comma separated values

Comment: but if i give range like Formula1:="=$AD$2:$AD$7" then its not corrupting. But its populating the dropdown with all comma separated values only. its not splitting

Comment: @aaroki - try to put them in inverted commas - `"a,b,c,d"` or to play a bit. Some ideas here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032944/getting-dynamic-dropdown-list-in-vba-validation

Comment: The values will be dynamic. not a static. it can be any range.